# Why is in-class using-declaration needed when inheriting from lambda types in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda, overloading, using

I wanted to make a utility that would allow to combine multiple lambdas into one overloaded functor. In C++17 it is actually quite easy, only about 5 lines of code:

```cpp
template <typename... Funcs>
struct overload : public Funcs... {
    using Funcs::operator()...;
    constexpr overload(Funcs&&... funcs) noexcept : Funcs{funcs}... {}
};
```

I am wondering why is the using-declaration required? Originally when I wrote this I didn't include the `using Funcs::operator()...;` line  and the compiler (GCC) complained about `operator()()` being ambiguous.

Why is the using-declaration necessary here? As far as I know, in-class using-declarations are used to make `protected` members of base classes `public` in the derived class. As lambda types already have `operator()()` declared as `public` the using-declaration shouldn't make a difference.

[Here is an example usage code (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/c3sf7z93v):

```cpp
auto f = overload{
    [](int){return "int ";},
    [](char){return "char ";},
    [](float){return "float ";},
    [](){return "void ";}
};
std::cout << f(3) << f('a') << f();
```

Comment: `struct A{ void f(int);}; struct B{ void f();}; struct C : A, B {}; C c; c.f();` would also be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The call operator has a name. It's name is `operator()`. The derived `operator()` name is the only candidate for name lookup when considering the derived class's interface.

The `operator()` of each base class must be imported into the namespace of the derived class otherwise it's not a candidate for name lookup.

It's the same as this:

```
struct base
{
  void foo();
};

struct derived : base
{
  // uncomment next line to allow this to compile
  // using base::foo;

  void foo(int);
};

void test(derived& d)
{
    // matches the signature of the base class's foo(), 
    // not the derived classes foo(int)
    d.foo();
}
```

In the above declaration, `derived::foo` is shadowing `base::foo` which is not available

Comment: Base class members are definitely candidates for name lookup. How else would they be found? Your example is different because name lookup stops in `derived` once the name is found. Additional candidates are hidden - overload resolution happens in a single scope, and your scope is `derived`. But in the question, there are 4 scopes at equal depth.

Comment: @MSalters At the moment the OP has only one answer. I'd be happy to remove this one if a better one is posted.